# Replacing a word in a sentence with another word

Tags: python-2.7, list, replace, utf-8, jupyter-notebook

If I have a list of sentences. I  need to traverse each sentence and check if any two words are the same in any two sentences. If yes then replace the word in the second sentence with a third word that is initialized. The third word is a common word (var3).  For example: Rahul is eating an apple. Rahul drinks milk. Output : Rahul Is eating an apple. He is drinking milk.

```
var3='तो' #word to replace if words are same 

summary=['Rahul drinks milk', 'Rahul eats rice', Seema is going to the market']
for sent in summary:
  occurences = [index for index, value in enumerate(summary) if value == sent]
  if len(occurences) > 1
for i in range(len(summary)):
    for word in i:
        var1=sent[i]
        var2=sent[i+1]
        if(var1==var2):
            var3=var1
```

summary is the list of sentences. Now in this case there are three sentences. Where "Rahul" is the same in two sentences. So the word in the second sentence is replaced.

Can somebody please help me out with this?

Comment: Which two sentences? Any two sentences? For each word of each sentence, you want to see if it appears in any other sentence? If so, you want to replace that word?

Comment: Yes. Any two sentences.  So if the word is there then replace the second word with var3. For example: Rahul is eating an apple. Rahul is drinking milk. Output : Rahul Is eating an apple. He is drinking milk.

Comment: In your example, what about the word `is`? Shouldn't the sample output have been: `Rahul is eating an apple. He He drinking milk` ?

Comment: In your code, where is the variable `i` defined?

Comment: Oh sorry. It will be just one word. Say suppose Rahul is eating an apple. Rahul drinks milk. Something like this

Comment: So there is only one common word to replace? Do you know what the common word is beforehand?

Comment: i is not defined. I was trying to use two for loops one to traverse each sentence and the other to traverse each word in that sentence.

Comment: Yes. The common word will be initialized first and only the same word in the second sentence is replaced with the common word.

Comment: Can you edit the original question to clarify all of these things discussed please? And also make another coding attempt first. What you need to do is iterate each sentence, and for each sentence, iterate with an index so that you can replace words while iterating. Once you've found the first occurrence of the word to replace, you can start replacing - this can be accomplished with a `boolean`.

Comment: I've edited it. I'm not sure whether the use of i is correct.

Comment: Try running the code and fixing the errors first. Why are you comparing pairs of adjacent words? Also, `var3=var1` will not modify the sentence since you are just assigning `var3`'s value. Try following the pseudocode I've given you. Also please edit your question. It doesn't match what you've explained to me here.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll make the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class People():
    def __init__(self,name,replace_with):
        self.name = name
        self.replace_with = replace_with
        self.first_encountered = False
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name+"  -- "+str(self.first_encountered)

sentences = ["Rahul is eating an apple.",
             "Rahul drinks milk.",
             "Rahul also drinks Beer.",
             "Rahul likes Pizza",
             "Seema is going to the market",
             "Seema also drinks beer",
             "and i am going to hell"
             ]

names= ["Rahul", "Seema"]
replaces = ["He","She"]

people = [ People(n,r) for n,r in zip(names,replaces) ]

new_sentence = []
found_in_any = [False,False]
for sentence in sentences:
    for index,person in enumerate(people):
        if(sentence.find(person.name)!=-1):
            found_in_any[index] = True           
            if(not person.first_encountered):
                person.first_encountered = True
                new_sentence.append(sentence)
                continue
            if(person.first_encountered):
                new_sentence.append(sentence.replace(person.name,person.replace_with)) 
        else:
            found_in_any[index] = False

        if len(list(set(found_in_any))) == 1 and list(set(found_in_any))[0] == False:
            new_sentence.append(sentence) 

print(new_sentence)

output : ['Rahul is eating an apple.',
 'He drinks milk.',
 'He also drinks Beer.',
 'He likes Pizza',
 'Seema is going to the market',
 'Seema is going to the market',
 'She also drinks beer',
 'and i am going to hell']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentences = ["Rahul is eating an apple.","Rahul drinks milk.","Rahul also drinks Beer.","Rahul likes Pizza","Seema is going to the market"]

new_sentence = [] first_encountered = False for sentence in sentences:
    if(sentence.find(replace)!=-1):
        if(not first_encountered):
            first_encountered = True
            new_sentence.append(sentence)
            continue
        if(first_encountered):
            new_sentence.append(sentence.replace(replace,replace_with)) 
    else:
        new_sentence.append(sentence) new_sentence
```

Output :

```
['Rahul is eating an apple.',
 'He drinks milk.',
 'He also drinks Beer.',
 'He likes Pizza',
 'Seema is going to the market']
```

Comment: Here sentence will have about 5-6 sentences. So I'm trying to compare two at a time to see if the words in it our same. @Pramit

Comment: Only Rahul in the second sentence is to be replaced not both the sentences.

Comment: Can it be done without initializing replace='Rahul'. Like traverse and check if the words are same if they are the same then replace it

Comment: the replace function is already doing it. traversing and checking.. why you have to do it again??

Comment: I meant you've mentioned what to replace. So here in this case replace=Rahul. But dynamically if it had to be done then it would check each word in each sentence to see if they are same. When a match is found , the word is replaced.

Comment: Please update your question correctly, Check the List version if it helps

Comment: For the code to know that the person is 'He' or 'She', you have to do NLP, to extract names of the person from a list of sentences. and then continue with the replacement. These type things are already there in NLP Library

Comment: You need to write some logic to identify the names (that is entities) from a sentence and then tag them as male(He) or female(She).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested solution

```
sen1 = "Rahul is eating an apple"
sen2 = "Rahul drinks milk"
var = "He"

for i in sen1.split(" "):
    if i in sen2.split(" "):
        sen2 = sen2.replace(i, var)

print(sen1)
print(sen2)
```

Output:
Rahul is eating an apple.
He drinks milk

Comment: Yes something like this. But how to traverse through many sentences and check ? @Starter